# Private method 'puts'? Can't pass cucumber test in RSpec Book's Codebreaker example

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm following along in the RSpec Book and I can't get the cucumber test to pass a certain spot. I've even tried running cucumber on the *source code* from the book and it still won't pass. I'm not sure if it's the fact that I'm using a newer version of cucumber but there must be a way to make it pass!

When I get to the point where the program should start a new game I'm told there's an undefined method 'puts'. Why is it undefined and how else should I capture what the program `puts` out in Cucumber? Running the test in RSpec to make sure the game puts the message works just fine, not sure how to make it pass in cucumber.

(Cucumber version 1.3.17, Ruby version 2.1.2)

Basically, I have these features:

```
Feature: code-breaker starts game
As a code-breaker
I want to start a game
So that I can break the code
Scenario: start game
    Given I am not yet playing
    When I start a new game
    Then I should see "Welcome to Codebreaker!"
    And I should see "Enter guess:"
```

and these step definitions:

```
    class Output
      def messages
        @messages ||= []
      end
      def puts(message)
        messages << message
      end
    end
    def output
      @output ||= Output.new
    end

    Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
    end

    When /^I start a new game$/ do
      game = Codebreaker::Game.new(output)
      game.start
    end

    Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
      output.messages.should include(message)
    end
```

and this ruby code:

```
    module Codebreaker

        class Game

            def initialize(output)
                @output = output
            end

            def start
                @output.puts 'Welcome to Codebreaker!'
            end
        end
    end
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
When I start a new game                     # features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:16
  private method `puts' called for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Output:0x007fa4ea200ad0> (NoMethodError)

  ./lib/codebreaker/game.rb:10:in `start'
  ./features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:18:in `/^I start a new game$/'
  features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:7:in `When I start a new game'
```

How do I fix this so that it passes in cucumber?

Comment: it's saying the method `puts` is private.  Can you edit your post and include the filenames associated with the code blocks you've provided?  Is your code online by chance?

Comment: Putting the code online would help! It's here now: https://github.com/craftykate/temp_codebreaker_folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of things that have changed since this RSpec Book was published but I got it working by replacing your `code_break_steps.rb` file with this:

```
Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
end

When /^I start a new game$/ do
  @messenger = StringIO.new
  game = Codebreaker::Game.new(@messenger)
  game.start
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
  expect(@messenger.string.split("\n")).to include(message)
end
```

RSpec 3 has a class that you're trying to overwrite called `Output` and it was causing way too much confusion.  I just simplified this so you're tests are still talking to each other along with `stdout`.

You can use the same `should` syntax on the last line but it will be deprecated soon so better to get used to the `expect` syntax I used.  For now if that's more confusing you can still use:

`@messenger.string.split("\n").should include(message)`

Comment: You fixed it! Thank you Anthony!! I guess I should find some updated tutorials on Cucumber while I go through the book. I struggled to find a more recent RSpec tutorial that was thorough. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Michael Hartl just updated his book (though I don't think he uses cucumber) and he does a great job going over testing.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out next. I didn't set out to learn Cucumber, just RSpec, but the RSpec Book uses Cucumber so heavily I had to figure out the issues. Thanks for your help! I modified your answer to get the next test to pass as well, so I think I'm doing pretty good now.

Comment: Upvote.  FWIW: the rspec book recommends using rspec 2.0.0, so this answer should help others that are using 3.x.  And the [rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted) isn't a tutorial, but there are lots of good examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following this book right now and tried Anthony's technique. But I got into trouble again a little later in the book (most probably because I'm kind of a beginner in Rails and couldn't translate Anthony's technique to another case ^^). But anyway, I found an easier way not to interfere with RSpec Output class and still not divert too much form the lesson flow:

- rename the project `Output` class to something else, say `OOutput`
- and change all `output` variables to `o_output`.

Et voilà ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make that particular example pass in only two adjustments on the same "codebreaker_steps.rb" file, so you can still follow the book's curriculum. You don't have to touch the class name, just the output() method following it.

RSpec 3 contains an output() method that causes conflicts when you try to define another output() method. So in knowing that, take the book's instructions:

```
def output
 @output ||= Output.new
end
```

and rename it to:

```
def see_output #new
 @output ||= Output.new
end
```

(or name it anything that makes sense for the project)

Then go down to your When() method definition:

```
When /^I start a new game$/ do
 game = Codebreaker::Game.new(output)
 game.start
end
```

and update the second line to:

```
When ("I start a new game") do
 game = Codebreaker::Game.new(see_output) #new
 game.start
end
```